# Simplest way to count the number of independent components of the Riemann-Christoffel curvature tensor

Tags: matrices, tensors, general-relativity

I have recently managed to convince myself that I know what tensors are. I convinced myself by first studying rotations and then learning about transformation rules and such.

A question that has been asked and answered many times is that of finding the number of independent components of a tensor. I am asking it again here in hopes of finally understanding how to do it.

The question I am looking at goes something like

Given $R_{iklm}$ (i) ---> 256

And the conditions

$R_{iklm} = -R_{ikml} = -R_{kilm}$  (ii)  ---> reduces to 36

$R_{iklm} = -R_{lmik} $  (iii) ---> reduces to 21

$R_{iklm} + R_{ilmk}  + R_{imkl} = 0$ (iv)---> reduces to 20

I happen to believe that the 256 is from 4 times 4 times 4 times 4.

What I did was construct $R_{iklm}$ as a tensor product of two rank 2 tensors.

There are many ways of breaking it up but the diagonals are seen to be zeros.

So I counted out 16 * 4 diagonal components = 64

I also counted out the repeating lower diagonal stuff  = 6 * 16 = 96 components

Then I counted out the diagonals of the upper diagonal 6 *4 = 24

I also counted out the lower diagonals of the  6 * 6 = 36

The tally is 256 - 64 -96 -24 -36 = 36

Hypercube diagonal planes vanish.

We are left with 36. This should take one from (i) to (ii)

Here is a picture I made with wolfram that probably gives away the reasoning.

[image]

How to go from (ii) to (iii)?

and  (iii) to (iv)?

Comment: You should remove the remarks where you belittle yourself. This is a good question.

Comment: Ok, I have now made the edits.